# Is there a citation for an apparent change in UK Tax Return calculation process, going into 2021/2

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, calculation

Examining my Tax Returns for the past 4 years, it seems that HMRC have changed one of their rounding policies (from previously being less accurate but in the individual's favour, to being more accurate)

Specifically, the Tax Return process works roughly by saying:

- Re-calculate your total income tax owed.
- Report the total income tax paid.
- Subtract the one from the other, to calculate the rebate/debt due.

For the years prior to 2021/2, it looked like the HMRC calculation has rounded step 2 upwards to the whole pound. So if you actually paid £10,329.32 then it would perform your rebate calculation as though you'd paid £10,330 (and thus return an extra 68p to you!)

However, for the year 2021/2, it seems like it's no longer doing that but is instead using the actual Tax amount paid for the subtraction (which seems fair, really :) )

Question:

**Is there a citation somewhere to confirm what I think I've found?**

*(Just to complete my satisfaction that I can fully account for the whole of my Tax Return calculation)*